# What's the value returned by pointer variable name?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I don't understand why the following code yields the following output, respectively:

```
char c[ 5 ] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
char* pc = c;
std::cout << pc;
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnl37.png)

I need to understand this because I'm doing an exercise where I need to find an index of an array through one pointer that points to that array. On web, I found a code like the following but I don't understand its result, although it solves my problem, I believe that if I understand the above code I could understand this:

```
char c[ 5 ] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
char* pc = &c[2];
int index = pc - c;
std::cout << index; // 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is not null-terminated, so `<<` keeps outputting characters beyond `"Hello"` until it finds a `'\0'` further in memory or even crashes. Try this instead:

```
char c[6] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
char* pc = c;
std::cout << pc;
```

Or, as @n.m. suggested:

```
char c[] = "Hello";
char* pc = c;
std::cout << pc;
```

> I believe that if I understand the above code I could understand this:
>
> ```
> char c[ 5 ] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
> char* pc = &c[2];
> int index = pc - c;
> std::cout << index; // 2
> ```

Here, `pc` is a `char` pointer to a memory address 2 x `char` higher than `c`. Subtracting those 2 pointers gives 2.

Doing `std::cout << pc;` or `std::cout << c + 2`; (with `c[6]`)

Would give: `llo` as output.

Comment: Better yet try `char c[] = "Hello";`.

Comment: @FernandoK. - Just added that to the answer.

Comment: I guess I understood the arithmetic, but why does the name of pointer returns the value pointed to, in this case "l",  and the remaining values of that array?

Comment: @FernandoK. - `pc` points to the first `'l'` in your string. Using `<<` with `pc` outputs the string starting at `'l'` until it encounters a `'\0'`. So you are saying: instead of printing the full string "Hello", start printing the same string, but this time start at `'l'`.

Comment: "starting at 'l' until it encounters a '\0'". This kind of thing I believe I can find if I search for std::cout, right?

Comment: @FernandoK. - Right, but other string handling functions need a terminating zero too. In C++ you would normally use `std::string`, but I undestand this is an excercise for array.

Comment: @FernandoK. - No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

When you `stream <<` a pointer to char, it prints characters until it encounters a character with the value 0. In your case it never does (not until it gets out of array bounds anyway) which is undefined behavior.

Try

```
char c[6] =  { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 };
```

Incidentally, you can (and probably should) initialize a char array with a string literal directly!

```
char c[] = "Hello";
```

This will automatically handle the null-termination, and if you've specified too small a dimension for the array, the compiler will complain.

```
char c[5] = "Hello"; //ERROR
```